# Make jLayeredPanes "solid"

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I have a GUI with a bunch of jPanels stacked on top of each other. Which one is "on top" is controlled by a jLayeredPane. 
However, when hovering over buttons and forms not on top, they become visible and interact-able.

How can I make the panels "solid" i.e. so that the underlying components don't "pop up"?

Comment: try `panel.setOpaque(true);`.

Comment: @Harry - That's what I thought, but no, already tried that.

Comment: don't understand the "become visible" - but the interact-able is to be expected: mouseEvents are delivered to the top-most component which is willing to receive it, they don't care if the comps are layered or normally added. Cant think a simple solution ... so stepping back and asking the usual (as implicitly already asked by @dacwe :) why do you use a layeredPane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise you to use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) for this task.

Comment: Alright... I'll give it a shot! So when should a jLayeredPane be used?

Comment: JLayeredPane should be used when components may overlap each other. (In your case you don't want that, you only want to see one at a time.)

Comment: +1 for [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html).

Answer (score 3):

> So when should a `JLayeredPane` be used?

Use [`Layered Pane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) when you want different layers visible at the *same time*. Use [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to replace the the *entire* pane.

Answer (score 3):

A technical solution to block mouseEvents, available since jdk7, is a JLayer (me still playing with it, that's why I show it occasionally :-)

```
public static class MouseBlockerUI extends LayerUI<JComponent> {

    @Override
    protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer l) {
        JLayeredPane layeredPane = (JLayeredPane) l.getParent();
        if (layeredPane.getLayer(l) != layeredPane.highestLayer())
            e.consume();
    }

    @Override
    public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        super.installUI(c);
        JLayer jlayer = (JLayer)c;
        jlayer.setLayerEventMask(
                AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK 
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
        JLayer jlayer = (JLayer)c;
        jlayer.setLayerEventMask(0);
        super.uninstallUI(c);
    }

}
```

then wrap your panels into a JLayer and add the JLayer to the JLayeredPane:

```
layeredPane.add(new JLayer(myPanel, new MouseBlockerUI(), someLayer));
```